# Use of completeness theorem in decidability of monadic predicate logic

Tags: logic

One way of proving the decidability of monadic predicate logic is via the finite model lemma:

> If a monadic formula F with $k$ unary predicates is satisfiable, then it is satisfiable in a domain with at most $2^k$ elements.

To prove this lemma we assume that F is satisfiable and construct a model with size $|2^k|$. Most proofs assume that decidability follows immediately from this lemma. However, isn't it also necessary to also show that if F is $not$ satisfiable, we can demonstrate this unsatisfiability by a finite procedure?

My guess is that this requires an implicit (but essential) appeal to the completeness theorem: if ~F is unsatisfiable, then ~F is refutable.

Comment: I agree, but I am studying proofs of decidability that pre-date completeness, in which case I think it needs to be shown.

Comment: Actually, I think I read too quickly. The lemma on its own seems to be enough. To determine whether $\varphi$ is satisfiable we look at all structures of appropriate size. Trivially there are no false positives, and the lemma says there are no false negatives. So there's no need to appeal to completeness at all: $\varphi$ is satisfiable iff it has a model of the appropriate size, which is checkable.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Why do you say "trivially there are no false positives"? I assume you mean a case where we wrongly think $\phi$ is satisfiable and it is not. Are you just implying that the procedure for finding a contradiction is trivial?

Comment: I'm not thinking in terms of searching for a contradiction at all. Read my answer. The process is: search for a model of size $\le n$ for $n$ appropriate; if you find one then the sentence is trivially satisfiable (no false positives), and if you don't find one then the sentence is unsatisfiable by the lemma (no false negatives).

Comment: Got it. But then doesn't my question just get pushed back to the hypothesis of the lemma? If we start with F and do not assume that it is satisfiable, the proof of the lemma doesn't go through. We also need to show what happens when the antecedent fails, no?

Comment: No, we don't: if $F$ **isn't** satisfiable, then obviously $F$ doesn't have any models of size $\le 2^k$. The lemma is an iff, but only one direction is nontrivial. I think you're overthinking this.

Comment: I've rewritten my answer to hopefully make this clearer. I think you may be trying to frame this proof-theoretically, but it's really best thought of purely model-theoretically: the only problem with brute-force model search as a test for satisfiability is that it's too hard, and the lemma fixes that.

Comment: Something I just noticed: are you sure you stated the lemma properly? "$\exists x,y(x\not=y)$" is a satisfiable sentence in the language with $0$ unary predicates but has no models of size $\le 2^0$. Maybe $k$ should be the length of $\varphi$ (that's what I originally read this as, and assumed in my answer) or you're restricting to equality-free sentences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the lemma on its own is enough.

Here's the decision procedure to tell if a monadic second-order sentence $\varphi$ using only unary relation symbols is satisfiable:

> Search through all structures in the language of $\varphi$ of size $\le 2^{\vert\varphi\vert}$ for a model of $\varphi$. If you find one, then $\varphi$ is satisfiable; if you don't find one, then $\varphi$ is not satisfiable.

We have to prove four things about this process:

- It's computable.
- It always halts and gives an answer.
- It never gives a false positive: if the algorithm says "$\varphi$ is satisfiable" then $\varphi$ is actually satisfiable.
- It never gives a false negative: if the algorithm says "$\varphi$ is not satisfiable" then $\varphi$ is actually not satisfiable.

The first two bulletpoints are immediate. The fourth bulletpoint (or rather, its contrapositive) follows from the lemma in the OP: by the lemma, if $\varphi$ is satisfiable then the algorithm above will indeed report $\varphi$ to be satisfiable.

The third bulletpoint meanwhile is trivial: the only way the algorithm declares $\varphi$ to be satisfiable is if it actually finds an actual model of $\varphi$, so by definition it can't falsely conclude that $\varphi$ is satisfiable.

Comment: Can you direct me to a source for how to prove a logic has the finite model property? Thanks.

Comment: @Mallik I don't know much about that topic unfortunately, since the systems I'm interested in very much *don't* have the finite model property.